# PLS HELP MySql Error 1054: Unknown column 'column name' in field list

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I made a stored procedure like this:

```
create procedure uppdateUser(newname varchar(25), newpass varchar(50), newname2 varchar(25), newpass2 varchar(50))
    -> begin
    -> while name=newname && pass=newpass do
    -> update users set name=newname2, pass=newpass2;
    -> end while;
    -> end
```

But I get an error `unknown column name in field list` when I call the procedure like this:

```
call uppdateUser('marky','mark','ice','cube');
```

I have searched questions here on StackOverflow but haven't found an answer. Can anyone explain to me what is the issue here in my query and how to fix it?

Comment: How does the engine know what name and pass are in `while name  && pass = newpass`  I see no variable declaration for name, and pass in your procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is the references to `name` and `pass` in the while condition. Those references aren't valid. There aren't any procedure parameters or variables with those names.

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but I don't think there's any need for a while loop.

It looks like you want a WHERE clause on the UPDATE statement. Without a WHERE clause, the UPDATE statement is going to update *every* row in the table. And there's no need to run that more than once.

I'd expect the update statement to be of the form something like this:

```
 UPDATE users
    SET name  = v_newname
      , pass  = v_newpass
  WHERE name  = v_oldname
    AND pass  = v_oldpass
```

But again, I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve.

First, get your UPDATE statement right. Figure out the actual SQL statements you want to execute.

Once you've got that, then you can put it into a stored procedure.

Comment: I need to change oldname i oldpass in the table (if it exists) with provided newname and newpass

Comment: for example if i have marky(name) mark(pass) in the table i have to check if it exists in the table and if it does then to uppdate it with newname2 and newpass 2

Comment: Thx @spencer7593 allot.You helped me solve this issue and understand where i did go wront

Comment: Sorry for misstyping some word...this helped me `UPDATE users
    SET name  = v_newname
      , pass  = v_newpass
  WHERE name  = v_oldname
    AND pass  = v_oldpass`